# restFixture - I'd like a assert a simple text response

Tags: automated-tests, fitnesse

This should be a pretty simple thing, but for some reason I am struggling to find an example anywhere.

I have been using the awesome restFixture for some time, and all my assertions are on json content that is returned.

We now have a microservice that is returning a pure text response (so not json, it's actually a csv). I am struggling to find out how to assert the pure text response!

I've used this before my GET request:

```
|Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixtureConfig|
|restfixture.content.handlers.map    |text/plain=TEXT   |
```

...but I am not sure how to assert the response.

The message I get back is:

java.lang.IllegalArgumentException: Cannot evaluate 'TOKEN,CARD_LOGO,TRANSACTION_DATE' in TOKEN,CARD_LOGO,TRANSACTION_DATE

My table looks like this:

```
!3 GET Report
|Table:smartrics.rest.fitnesse.fixture.RestFixture|${ReportServiceEndPoint}     |
|setHeader                                        |${ReportServiceHeader}            |                              |
|GET                                              |?transactionDateFrom=${myTransactionDateFrom}&transactionDateTo=${myTransactionDateTo}&requestorId=${myRequestorId} |${myResponseCode}||${myExpectedResultThatOnlyChecksHeaders}|
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated, as I will soon have to do more complex assertions on this text response.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know how/whether it can be done by restFixture, but [my HttpTest fixture](https://github.com/fhoeben/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/wiki/2.-Slim-Fixtures#httptest) allows you to capture any response (and perform a check on the full content, possibly using [Slim's regular expression support](http://www.fitnesse.org/FitNesse.FullReferenceGuide.UserGuide.WritingAcceptanceTests.SliM.ValueComparisons)). Alternatively you can place the response in a Slim variable and then do assertions by applying regular expressions using [StringFixture](http://fhoeben.github.io/hsac-fitnesse-fixtures/examples-results/HsacExamples.SlimTests.UtilityFixtures.StringFixtureTest.html).

I suppose restFixture also allows access to the 'raw' response. So this should be possible there also.

Comment: Thank you. I want to keep using restFixture for this but I do have a need for the HttpTestFixture at some point as I have some Soap services to test. I will try getting the response out into a symbol as you suggest.